# Sending a File via a secure connection with Indy to a website

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have to send an XML-File to a Website with a secure Connection. Delphi 2010, Indy 10.5.9. The Code used is as follows:

```
  Params: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
  ResponseStr: string;
begin
  result := 0;
  sRootCertFile := 'xxx\Digital.pem';
  sCertFile := 'xxx\Digital.pem';
  sKeyFile := 'xxx\Digital.pem';
  with FAdminSetup.RDWSSLHandler do
  begin
    SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
    SSLOptions.RootCertFile := sRootCertFile;
    SSLOptions.CertFile := sCertFile;
    SSLOptions.KeyFile := sKeyFile;
  end;
  sURL := 'https://xxx/xxxservice';
  begin
    IdHttpVVO := TIdHttp.Create(nil);
    try
//      IdHttpVVO.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';    
//      IdHttpVVO.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
//      IdHttpVVO.HTTPOptions := [hoKeepOrigProtocol,hoForceEncodeParams];
//      IdHttpVVO.Request.Connection    := 'Keep-Alive';
//      IdHttpVVO.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
//      IdHttpVVO.Request.ContentLength := Length(sAnsiXML); // <-- new
      IdHttpVVO.IOHandler := FAdminSetup.RDWSSLHandler;
      Params := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
      try
        with Params do
        begin
          AddFile('file', filename, GetMIMETypeFromFile(filename));
        end;
        resultStr := IdHttpVVO.Post(sURL, Params);
      finally
        Params.Free;
      end;
      ShowMessage(resultstr);
```

The result is always the same: 
'HTTP/1.0 500 Error'
when doing the post part. 
All the remarks have been tried and did not give any change. The Password for the connection is supplied as follows:

```
procedure TFAdminSetup.RDWSSLHandlerGetPasswordEx(ASender: TObject;
  var VPassword: AnsiString; const AIsWrite: Boolean);
begin
  VPassword := 'xxx';
end;
```

The Website is working, the certificates seem to be ok, as there is a small tool included written in C that works.

Where is my mistake? Thanks